# Have to built solution before debugging

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010

I develop a ASP MVC site, when I press F5 to debug, VS appear a notice error (as picture). If built solution, then debug, that error don't appear.

Plz help me fix this error

[alt text http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/1969/screenhunter02jul051427.gif](http://img692.imageshack.us/img692/1969/screenhunter02jul051427.gif)

Comment: Do you have any custom actions in your build script?

Answer (score 0):

The error appears to be a `Castle.Windsor` configuration error. Are you sure your application has the correct configuration section?

Comment: I sure. Because when I built solution and debug, the erros don't appear

Answer (score 0):

Check the Castle.Windsor references in your project. Also check the web.config for your Castle.Windsor configuration, may be one of the types haven't been mentioned properly. Try putting in the fully qualified name like "Castle.Windsor.Configuration.AddDomain.CastleSectionHandler"